# Humanized Enso crashing randomly under windows 7, 8, 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10

Humanized Enso is an application launcher that lets you launch apps on windows by simply holding the caps key, while typing "open 'shortcut name here'".
Problem is, it has been discontinued, and while it currently runs on windows versions up to 10, it is slowly getting rusty. 
Question is:
Does anyone know of a fix for these random crashes? and if not,
Does someone know of a fork of its [source code](https://github.com/GChristensen/enso-portable) that is more compatible with the latest windows operating systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be fair, I find it amazing that no one has made a re-make of Enso yet when the idea is so great... In my opinion the only alternative that's worth recommending at the moment is [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/index.php). Not as intuitive as Enso though...

Comment: Thanks, as you said is not as intuitive as Enso, but works very well

Comment: FYI this portable version of Enso works fine on my Windows 8.1 Pro system: https://github.com/GChristensen/enso-portable

Answer (score 0):

An other option could be [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), is not exactly a launcher, and needs a little more effort, but is very powerful, and it can simplify some tasks. The application doesn't work by itself, you have to make a script with instructions of what to do.

There is also a big list of scripts to download in the website and many tutorials to create your own.